# Passing value from html input to python script with Django

Tags: python, django

So basically what I have been trying to figure out is how to pass the value from the form into a python script with Django.

Here is my form code, I want to pass that value of stateLand into the python script.

```
<form action= '*******' method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
    Land: <input type="text" name="stateLand" />
    </br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Here is my view.

```
def ar(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        from raids import state
        x = state("","")
        return render(request, 'ar.html', {'state':x.main('24000')})
    else:
        return render(request, 'ar.html')
```

Right now I have just 24000 hard coded into the script. I have tried many things to get this to work but none have seemed to help. Any suggestions you guys have to make this work? The python script runs some calculations on the number entered.

I've tried different things like

```
request.POST.get('stateLand')

stateLand  = form.getvalue("stateLand")

import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
stateLand = form["stateLand"]
```

Comment: I always use `request.POST.get('stateLand', '')`

Comment: well that was simple.... all I needed was the , ' ' )  I guess that makes sense for having the default value if nothing is supplied though.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. You need to access the post arguments with `requests.get`:

```
def ar(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        state = request.POST['stateLand']
        return render(request, 'ar.html', {'state':state}) # this just returns whatever was posted as stateland right now
    else:
        return render(request, 'ar.html')
```

Comment: can't seem to get that to work either. the x = state("","") is just creating a blank object of a class to call it's main function. When i use the requests.get it gives me this error Invalid URL u'stateLand': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant ht tp://stateLand?                                `def ar(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        from raids import state
        stateLand = requests.get('stateLand')
        x = state("","")
        return render(request, 'ar.html', {'state':x.main(stateLand)})
    else:
        return render(request, 'ar.html')`

Comment: requests.get uses a URL to grab data from. So it wouldn't work unless I can somehow grab the specific value from it.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I think that would have worked for a get method. SInce you're using post, you typically use a form too, and check to see if it's valid in your view. The above code might work without one. Here is also link on properly using views with forms:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#the-view

Answer (score 0):

Also you can create class view with certain method:

```
class MyClass(View):
    def post(self, request):
        data=request.POST

        #will be better to use django forms
        #form = self.MyClassForm(data=data)
        #if form.is_valid():

        stateLand  = data.get("stateLand", None)
```